# .Continue starts before task is completed

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have the following code in C#, VS2012, WPF 4.5.
My expectation would be that, `.ContinueWith` will be executed after the task has finished completely (that's a continuation's whole purpose, isn't it?).

This should result in a value of 2 in `finalResult`.

```
int myTestInt = 0;

Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
   myTestInt = 1;
   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
   myTestInt = 2;

}).ContinueWith(_ =>
   {
      int finalResult = myTestInt;
   });
```

In fact, `finalResult` is assigned a value of 1 instead. So it seems like the continuation is started on the `await` statement already.

Is this the intended behaviour? Am I missing something here? Can't I rely on `ContinueWith`to start after a task has completely finished?

Update:

Justin's answer just inspired me to check the following:

```
int myTestInt = 0;
Task task=Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
{
   myTestInt = 1;
   await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));
   myTestInt = 2;
});

task.Wait();
int result2 = myTestInt;
```

finalResult is still set to 1. Is there no way to reliably wait for a task that contains `await`s to complete?

Comment: I think you should invoke `Task.Delay` directly - not using the `await` keyword.

Comment: You'll notice that `_` is actually a `Task<Task>`, which fully supports what Justin is saying...

Comment: In fact, using Task.Delay(6) will produce the expected result, but will not wait 6 seconds. I think it would be pretty much the same to delete the whole line.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you pass an `async` delegate to `Task.Factory.StartNew`, the returned `Task` only represents the first portion of that delegate (up until the time it `await`s something that is not already completed).

However, if you pass an `async` delegate to the new `Task.Run` method (which was included for this reason), the returned `Task` represents the entire delegate. So you can use `ContinueWith` as you expect. (Although `await` is usually a better option than `ContinueWith`).

For more information on `StartNew` vs `Run`, see [Stephen Toub's post on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

The await will immediately return control to the calling function, which in this case is the StartNew of your task.  This means the task will then complete and execute the ContinueWith.
If you really want task to complete before the ContinueWith, then don't await the Task.Delay.

Comment: I think you're right - await marks the current task as completed. Although it's not (at least not from a semantical point of view). As await's are a basic building block of all software today, that means never to rely on ContinueWith anymore. Don't you think, that's a bug?

Answer (score -1):

I saw this in the MSDN: :-)

```
public async  void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Image = await Task.Run(async() =>
    {
        using(Bitmap bmp1 = await DownloadFirstImageAsync())
        using(Bitmap bmp2 = await DownloadSecondImageAsync())
        return Mashup(bmp1, bmp2);
    });
}
```

So do not forget the **"async()**" !!!

Comment: His code has the `async` his problem is he is using `TaskFactory` which does not have a overload that takes in a `Func<Task>` or a `Func<Task<T>>` which `Task.Run` does have.